# Spring JUnit ApplicationContextInitializer parameters

Tags: java, spring, junit, environment

We have implemented an extended .properties format. Such a properties file can contain an optional include property. The value of this properties is the classpaths of other properties files to load recursively.

I could configure the Spring environment for my application but I have a problem to engage this mechanism with `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner`.

I thought I could use the `initializer` property of the `ContextConfiguration` annotation but it looks it can only be instantiated with a no-arg constructor.

I need to give it the root file of my properties files hierarchy. It could eventually be another annotation on my test class, but again, how can I access it ?

The only think I have found so far is to set this file as a system property in my test class static initializer. ugly?:

```
@ActiveProfiles("qacs.controller.channels=mock")
@ContextConfiguration(initializer=ContainerTestContextInitializer.class)
public class QacsControllerTest 
{
   static
   {
      System.setProperty(ContainerTestContextInitializer.SYSTEM_PROPERTY, "classpath:com/xxx/qacs/QacsControllerTest.properties");
   }
   @Test
   void test() {}
   }
}

public class ContainerTestContextInitializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext>
{
   public static final String SYSTEM_PROPERTY = "icomp.test.properties";
   @Override
   public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext pApplicationContext)
   {
      String path = System.getProperty(SYSTEM_PROPERTY);
      if (path == null)
      {
         throw new IllegalStateException("Missing system property " + SYSTEM_PROPERTY);
      }

      final DefaultPropertiesLoader loader;
      loader = new DefaultPropertiesLoader(System.getProperties());
      try
      {
         loader.load(path);
      }
      catch (IOException e)
      {
         throw new IllegalStateException(e.getMessage(), e);
      }

      MutablePropertySources sources = pApplicationContext.getEnvironment().getPropertySources();
      MapPropertySource mps = new MapPropertySource(Launcher.ICOMP_PROPERTY_SOURCE, (Map) loader.getProperties());
      sources.addFirst(mps);
   }
}
```

Comment: You could use a well known system/environment property and/or default for it instead of passing it to the constructor (maybe you can show the code). If you would use the `Environment` that is available through the `COnfigurableApplicationContext` property of the `ApplicationContextInitializer`. That way if you lookup the property (to start loading from) you will consult the servletcontext(local to servlet and global)/system properties and finally the environment properties. You could then in your test set a system property to load it.

Comment: yes, that's basically what I have so far. However, it will be cleaner to give the path to the properties file through an additional annotation on QacsControllerTest, or be able to pass it directly in the ContextConfiguration annotation, for example.

Comment: And why would that be cleaner? The latter is more flexible. Tip instead of `System.getProperty` and do checking your self use the environment. `pApplicationContext.getEnvironment().getRequiredProperty(SYSTEM_PROPERTY)`. Saves you a check and instead of loading the properties yourself use a `ResourcePropertySource`. That way your code will reduce to about 4 lines. Also I don't see anything in your code that you couldn't do with a normal `@PropertySource(name=Launcher.ICOMP_PROPERTY_SOURCE, value="${icomp.test.properties}")` on your configuration class, you still need the system property though.

Comment: AFAIK ResourcePropertySource will not process other files inside my custom include properties (it will create a property 'include' with the path as value). It is the same for the annotation @PropertySource.

Comment: Neither will the code you posted here, what it does it only adds properties to the System properties. Which could even be dangerous if you use the same in multiple applications, one could override the other. Unless that is inside your `DefaultPropertiesLoader`.